# Unserialize в запросе SQL

Tags: sql

Есть следующее значение столбца хранящегося в базе данных:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:2:"id1";i:1;s:2:"id2";}
```

Возможно ли в SQL запросе десериализовать строку чтоб сделать выборку согласно имеющихся в этой строке данных? Возможно можно сделать проверку каким-то другим способом, буду благодарен за любые рабочие варианты.

---

Нашел решение:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '.*;s:[0-9]+:"value".*'
```

[Вариант от david-giorgi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28245643/9380123)

Comment: а что вы именно хотите видеть в результате?

Comment: А что за формат такой ? вообще строковыми функциями можно что угодно из строки достать. А какие функции есть в вашей СУБД посмотрите в документации на нее. В каждом SQL свой набор функций и возможностей, а диалект в вопросе вы не указали, кстати

Comment: Судя по заголовку и строке - это формат функций serialize в PHP. За пределами php смысла не несёт, да и спецификации на формат как таковой нет. Не предполагается использование вне PHP. В PHP впрочем тоже осторожно надо с этим. Если надо по этому искать - лучше будет заменить формат хранения.

Comment: Решение напишите в ответе. И потом можете принять его.

Comment: Не позволяет мне добавить ответ :)